# Encapsulate a postgresql Transaction in a structure

Tags: postgresql, rust, lifetime

I'm trying to encapsulate a Postgresql transaction and I'm running into some lifetime issue.

Here is the code :
[Code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=39033c6ddefcb3eaf1e93b5e5aff96ed)

I understand the error message : "returns a value referencing data owned by the current function"

But I have no idea how I could keep my "Transaction" in my the SQLConnection structure.

```rust
use postgres::{Client, NoTls, Transaction};

pub struct SQLConnection<'a> {
    client: Client,
    transaction: Transaction<'a>,
}

impl<'a> SQLConnection<'a> {
    pub fn new(connect_string: &str) -> Self {
        let mut client = Client::connect(connect_string, NoTls).unwrap();
        let transaction = client.transaction().unwrap();
        Self {
            client,
            transaction,
        }
    }

    pub fn commit(&self) {
        let _ = self.transaction.commit();
    }

    pub fn rollback(&self) {
        let _ = self.transaction.rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the concept of SQL transaction clear for you ? If not you should have a look before continuing.

Comment: Yes, the concept of SQL transaction is perfectly clear. It groups many queries together in order to keep the coherence of the system until you commit all the changes at once and make the changes visible by all other sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that suits my needs. I have now SQLConnection and SQLTransaction and I get the SQLTransation from the my connection.
Now I can use my transaction to group my elementary sql operations.

Here is the [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=416764795494f50b4c539d8e762625fa):

```rust
use postgres::{Client, NoTls, Transaction};

pub struct SQLConnection {
    client: Client,
}

impl SQLConnection {
    pub fn new(connect_string: &str) -> Self {
        let client = Client::connect(connect_string, NoTls).unwrap();
        Self { client }
    }

    pub fn transaction(&mut self) -> SQLTransaction {
        let t = self.client.transaction().unwrap();
        SQLTransaction { transaction: t }
    }
}

pub struct SQLTransaction<'a> {
    transaction: Transaction<'a>,
}

impl<'a> SQLTransaction<'a> {
    pub fn new(transaction: Transaction<'a>) -> Self {
        Self { transaction }
    }

    pub fn commit(self) {
        let _ = self.transaction.commit();
    }

    pub fn rollback(self) {
        let _ = self.transaction.rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious what is the value added by the `SQLTransaction` wrapper over just using `postgres::Transaction` directly? Also, both your `commit()` and `rollback()` just ignore errors, which is extremely dangerous because it might cause the program to proceed thinking everything is fine, when in reality a commit (or rollback) didn't occur. If you don't expect errors to occur, I would suggest replacing `let _ = self.transaction.commit();` with `self.transaction.commit.unwrap();`, so that the program panics if the error does happen after all.

Comment: You're totally correct about the error handling. It's not my intend to ignore them but it was not the subject of the post indeed 
I could pass the Transaction itself but I wanted to encapsulate all specific pg structures into a personal crate to have small abstraction. So the main program doesn't know it talks to postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

You' re returning a reference to a value you don't keep. You can't have a reference if there's no owned value.

In your case, there's also no reason to keep both the client and the transaction. Your connection should wrap the `client` but not the `transaction` which is a short lived object and shouldn't be kept for more than just the operation.

Your connection should thus just be

```
pub struct SQLConnection {
    client : Client,
}
```

Then you should, for an operation, get a `transaction`, use it, then drop it while keeping the connection.

Comment: Actually, it's what I did first. But keeping the client is not what I really want to do. I'd like to pass the same transaction to different routines that performs "inserts" for example. But I am stuck because it's impossible to encapsulate the pg transaction so far.